# AdMob Adaptive Banners. Get DisplayMetrics from Context

Tags: android, android-activity, admob, android-context, firebase-admob

I want to use the newly introduced [Google AdMob Adaptive Banners](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive) in my app. The quickstart illustrates a function to dynamically calculate the AdSize by DisplayMetrics.

```
private AdSize getAdSize() {
    // Step 2 - Determine the screen width (less decorations) to use for the ad width.
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float widthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels;
    float density = outMetrics.density;

    int adWidth = (int) (widthPixels / density);

    // Step 3 - Get adaptive ad size and return for setting on the ad view.
    return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth);
}
```

But this function uses getWindowManager() of Activity for calculation. But I just pass Context to my Class. Anyway to get the DisplayMetrics with Context?

Answer (score 4):

Easily accomplished.

This bit

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
```

can be replaced with this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
```

Answer (score 0):

If are you using Cordova can use this:

```
this.cordova.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
```